# create id column using php loop

Tags: php

I want an id column generated by php loop and I tried the code below.

This code is working but it skips first row. For e.g. if there are 153 rows, it shows only 152 rows because it skips first row and starts numbering from second row.

```
 $i = 0;
 $result = mssql_query ($sql);
 $cell = mssql_fetch_array($result);
 while ($i <= $cell & $cell = mssql_fetch_array($result))

{
$i = $i + 1;
echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[0]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[1]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[2]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[3]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[4]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[5]."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

 }
```

Comment: `$i <= $cell` ? at the first "round" of the loop `$cell` is not even defined. If that's not enought , `$cell` is an array and `$i` is an integer , why are you comparing them?

Comment: Try to remove this line `$record = mssql_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: sorry edited it should be $cell

Comment: Was it intentional to have `$i <= $cell & $cell = ...`, or did you mean `$i <= $cell && $cell = ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $i = 0;
 $result = mssql_query ($sql);
 //$record = mssql_fetch_array($result); - you don't need this
 while ($cell = mssql_fetch_array($result)) //you dont need $i <= $cell 

{
$i++; //$i = $i + 1;
echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[0]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[1]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[2]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[3]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[4]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$cell[5]."</td>";
echo "</tr>";

 }
```

Comment: It's even beter echo "<tr><td>".++$i."</td>";

Answer (score 5):

```
$cell = mssql_fetch_array($result);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     fetches the first record

while ($i <= $cell & $cell = mssql_fetch_array($result))
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                         fetches the second record
```

You're never outputting the first record you're fetching.
No idea what you're trying to do with that `$i` condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you probably want && instead of & here:

```
while ($i <= $cell & $cell = mssql_fetch_array($result))
```